# Process a function in parallel using python

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I have a process which takes about 10 seconds to run. The following function will take about 100 seconds for ten title entries:

```
for title in titles_to_update:
    run_update_procedure(title)
```

what would be the best way to parallelize this procedure. Would

```
pool = Pool(2)
pool.map(run_update_procedure, list(titles_to_update))
```

be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Parallel processing is not guaranteed to speed up your code. What is bottleneck? cpu? IO? waiting on resource? etc

Comment: The actual `run_update_procedure()` is an API call that takes about 20 seconds to finish -- it's basically us just waiting on their API to process the request and give us what we need.

Comment: If it's CPU-bound, there's probably nothing to be gained by specifying more processes than you have CPU cores.  In any case, you want one of the Pool "map" functions, to spread the work across all the processes.  `apply_async()` will pass the entire list to a single process.  Try something! ;-)

Comment: If it is external API, and you do not have limitations on number of call per second or number of simultaneously evaluated calls, then I think multiprocessing.Pool is a way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have spare cores to use on the system, and this is the case by your clarifications in comments, then `.map` is a good choice.
By the way for the type of task you described I would probably use `.imap_unordered`. Look at the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered).